# TemplatedParent is null when used inside a ControlTemplate's DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, wpf-style

Consider this (edited-down) `Style`, designed for a `Button` whose `Content` is a `String`:

```
<Style x:Key="Test" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                   <TextBlock x:Name="demo" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <system:String>Test</system:String>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter TargetName="test" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The intention in this example is to turn the button text red if it equals the word "Test"<sup>1</sup>. But it doesn't work, because the trigger's `TemplatedParent` binding resolves to null instead of to the `Button` the `Style` is applied to. However, the `TextBlock` named "demo" will have its `Text` set to "System.Windows.Controls.Button: [ButtonText]" as expected, which means `TemplatedParent` works correctly at that level. Why doesn't it work inside the `DataTrigger`?

---

<sup>1</sup> I know there are other ways to achieve that, but I'm trying to understand why the binding doesn't work the way I expect it to.

Comment: does it help, if you change 1. DataTrigger -> Trigger and 2. TemplatedParent -> Self in trigger?

Comment: @ASh Yes that does work, but for my actual case I need to use a `DataTrigger` because I am really working with a non-DependencyProperty of the TemplatedParent.

Comment: The reason is basically that RelativeSource is trying to resolve a parent by walking up the visual tree till it reach the condition. But in this case you upply the binding on a non visual element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TemplatedParent` in your `ControlTemplate.Triggers` is not what you expect. Inside trigger it actually references `Button.TemplatedParent`. As such, it will only be non-null if your create that *button* inside template. You don't create button inside template, so it is null in your case. Now consider this xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Test"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="text"
                                   Text="dummy" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="demo"
                                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <system:String>Test</system:String>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter TargetName="text"
                                    Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Test2" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Test}"></Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--<Button Content="Test" Style="{StaticResource Test}"/>-->
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Test2}" Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```

Here I retemplate `ContentControl` and inside template I use *button with your template*. If you run this code, you will see "dummy" text in red, because `Button.TemplatedParent` is now `ContentControl`, and it has it's `Content` equals "Test", which confirms what I said above.

Now back to your problem: just change `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` to `RelativeSource Self` (no need to change `DataTrigger` to `Trigger`) - this one would reference your Button.

Comment: You are clearly right. Does this imply that the trigger is "scoped" to the Button itself even though it is defined within the Button's Template? Is there some principle in play here that would have lead me to expect that if I'd known it?

Comment: You can think of it like that: whatever is inside ControlTemplate (StackPanel etc) are children of that template. Whenever you create new Button with your ControlTemplate, all those children will be created every time, based on template. Triggers are not "children" of template, they are kind of part of template definition, and not "created out of template" every time you create new Button. You can also make difference between visual controls (those children in template) and non-visual (trigger).

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a similar issue in .NET Core WPF.
My `DataTrigger` was not firing with `{Binding MyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}`, but instead when I changed the RelativeSource to `Self` the binding started to work. I'm not sure whether it's a hack or a solution, but it worked.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that my template was based on `MyView` (see below) and I was binding to a `DependencyProperty` on `MyView`.

So my final code looked like this:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Template" TargetType="{x:Type ns:MyView}">
    <!-- Some template -->

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure, but I think the trigger equals by referenc, because Content returns an Object. So it will never be true with your string defined within the trigger.

Comment: Pretty sure since `String` implements `IEquatable<String>`, WPF will use `String.Equals()` for the comparison. But in any case, the approach works fine if I change the DataTrigger to an ordinary Trigger. Further, by using [QuickConverter](https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/), I can confirm that the TemplatedParent binding is evaluating to null in that (but only that) case.

Comment: Well, that makes sense.
But I got an similiar problem when i used DataTemplates. I coudn't use DataTriggers on Controls within the Temlpate. That happened because the triggers are in seperate Namespace (Logical Tree) than the Template itself. Maybe that's the same reason here.